Unity high res mesh brighter than low res mesh despite using the same material
I'm currently making an LOD system for terrain. I have a high-res mesh:

And a low-res mesh:

As you can see, the high-res mesh is significantly brighter than the low-res mesh. They are definitely using the same material. Is there a fix for this?
Edit: Fixed. This was caused by multiple instances of the mesh being on top of itself (which was further caused by the subdiv mesh lingering between runs)
StackOverflow wants me to add more details because this post contains pictures. That's what these sentences are.
